# Accessing folder from Linux machine from Windows and linux

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have created shared folder (common_folder) on Linux, which I want to access by Windows as well as Linux System.

Programming language is Java. I am using "//IP address/common_folder" as folder path so that it will be accessible to both Linux and Windows.

{{ File folder = new File("//IP address/common_folder"); }}

When I am trying to get the folder using above line in Linux machine, it gives folder path as: "/root/eclipse///IP address/common_folder".
However I want only '//IP address/common_folder' as a folder path because my folder is available on that path.

How to get the folder of mentioned path in Linux using java?

Comment: You can create a symbolic link or mount so `//hostname` points to the same thing as windows mounts.  You can setup automounts to do the same thing automagically.

Comment: @Peter: Could you please elaborate more as I did not understand? And thanks for quick reply.

Comment: In linux you can add mount points to anywhere you need them to be, either statically or dynamically, If you add a mount point for `//hostname` or `//IPaddress` it will point to either the samba or nfs mount of your choice. In any case, how `File` is used to fine files/directories this is entirely down to OS configuration rather than Java.

Comment: Could you please explain how to mount a point in OpenSUSE? as I am new to Linux.

Comment: I would read this https://tr.opensuse.org/SDB:Access_to_Windows_Shares

Answer (score 1):

You have to use File.separator present in java lib