# Read a text file into list in Java

Tags: java, linux

Python has a method `lines = f.read().splitlines()` by which we can read a file into list. Do we have a similar method in Java?

Comment: Probable duplicate. Please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769038/accessing-folder-from-linux-machine-from-windows-and-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Scanner` and then read `line by line` and insert the line into a list

```
Scanner fileScanner= new Scanner(new File("yourfile.txt");
List<String> lines=new ArrayList();
while(scanner.hasNext()){
   String line = scanner.next();
   lines.add(line);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File in= new File(new URI("file://server/folder/text.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Note: The file path has to be a URI that can't contain spaces.

Comment: line by line is taking too much time. There are around 100 files and each file contains 10,000 lines. Is there any other fast method?

Answer (score 0):

Files conains static metods https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

```
new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)))
    .split(System.lineSeparator);
```